# Android - Activities can not be opened from another activity in Android 5

Tags: android, android-activity

I use the following piece of code to open an activity, and I think that's the correct way of doing this.

```
var intent = new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(Store));
StartActivity(intent)
```

When I test the application on my Nexus 4 which runs Android 5.0.1, the activities do not open. When I test the same application on my Nexus 7 which runs Android 4.4.4, I have no problems with my application. What makes the difference?
By the way, I use Xamarin to develop the application.

**EDIT:**
This is C# code, I use Xamarin.

Comment: First line should be Intent intent=new Intent(this.ApplicationContext, typeof(Store)); what's var intent ???

Comment: This is not valid Java code. Please copy and paste the code you use.

Comment: Do not use ApplicationContext, but context from Activity. So passing `this` instead of `this.ApplicationContext` should solve your problem.

Comment: How is Store declared? does Store class inherit from Android.App.Activity?

Comment: @AADTechnical Yes, Store is an activity

Comment: ok, as mentioned by @skywall, try using your Activity's ref. while creating an intent. For example: do like this `var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(Store));` and `StartActivity(intent)`

Comment: Thank you guys, I tested the method you mentioned, but still I have the same problem :(. any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity2));

StartActivity(intent);